# how to email output from measure-command

Tags: email, powershell, powercli

I'm looking for a way to email the output from the **measure-command** command.

I have a script that runs the `vmfs.unmap` command and I would like to use `measure-command` to tell us how long it took and then email us the results once completed.

So far, I have:

`Measure-Command {.\VMware_vmfsunmap.ps1}`

which outputs:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 11
Milliseconds      : 913
Ticks             : 119139896
TotalDays         : 0.000137893398148148
TotalHours        : 0.00330944155555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.198566493333333
TotalSeconds      : 11.9139896
TotalMilliseconds : 11913.9896
```

I can't figure out how to get the output into a email.
I have tried piping this into the `send-mailmessage` but it didn't work.

I can output it into an txt file using `Out-File` but then I'm not sure how to add that text to the body of an email.

I tried adding in a variable that says

```
$body = c:\scripts\output.txt
```

then

```
Send-MailMessage -From "vmfsunmap" -To "ME" -Subject "test vmfs unmap email" -Body **$Body** -SmtpServer smtpserver.com
```

but this just opened the txt file and didn't attach it into the body.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: i forgot to add that my powershell skills are very limited and im just learning this stuff... im sure im missing something basic but i dont know what!

Comment: ive also tried outputting to a txt file and then attaching the .txt file but that doesnt seem to work either.. theres no attachment in the email!

Send-MailMessage -From "vmfsunmap" -To "ME" -Subject "test vmfs unmap email" -Body "unmap completed successfully" -Attachments "txtfile.txt" -SmtpServer smtpserver.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Body-parameter has to be a string so try piping the output to `Out-String` and see if that works for ya.

```
Measure-Command {.\VMware_vmfsunmap.ps1} | Out-String
```

The difference could be verified with something like this;

```
(Measure-Command {.\VMware_vmfsunmap.ps1} | Out-String).GetType().FullName
```

Should output **System.String**

```
(Measure-Command {.\VMware_vmfsunmap.ps1}).GetType().FullName
```

Should output **System.TimeSpan**

Comment: `$body = Measure-Command {.\VMware_vmfsunmap.ps1} | Out-String` then use $body in your Send-MailMessage

Comment: oh ok.. that makes more sense now.. ok ill try it out